# How to get the parent and child ids from location

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

In my url i have the id's like this:

`http://localhost:3000/#/projectSummary/2/3?id`

from this I need to get both `2` (parent id) and 3 (child id) using the `$location.search`

how to get that both seperately. because i need to request 2 seperate query here.

at present i am using :

```
console.log( $location.search('id') );
```

It giving me as :

```
{$$protocol: "http", $$host: "localhost", $$port: 3000, $$path: "/projectSummary/2/3", $$search: Object…}$$absUrl: "http://localhost:3000/#/projectSummary/2/3?id"$$compose: ()$$hash: ""$$host: "localhost"$$parse: (d)$$parseLinkUrl: (a,c)$$path: "/projectSummary/2/3"$$port: 3000$$protocol: "http"$$replace: false$$search: Object$$state: null$$url: "/projectSummary/2/3?id"
```

from this how i can get both id's `2` and `3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANGULAR**

`$location.search()` will output `id`

Now that we have `id` separate, lets get the other values...

`$location.path()` will output `/#/projectSummary/2/3`

Now you can do this: `$location.path().replace("/#/projectSummary/", "");` which should give you `2/3`

But really we want to do this: `$location.path().replace("/#/projectSummary/", "").split("/");` giving you an array of the separate values.

Now all three values are separated and ready to be put into your next string.

**Pure JS**

You need to work with JavaScript's Location Object.

`window.location.search` will output `id`

Now that we have `id` separate, lets get the other values...

`window.location.pathname` will output `/#/projectSummary/2/3`

Now you can do this: `window.location.pathname.replace("/#/projectSummary/", "");` which should give you `2/3`

But really we want to do this: `window.location.pathname.replace("/#/projectSummary/", "").split("/");` giving you an array of the separate values.

Now all three values are separated and ready to be put into your next string.